# Script to delete photo from facebook fan page cover album

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have posted so many images on my facebook page, and all old updates are showing publiclly on time my page's timeline, is there any way to  delete photo from facebook fan page cover album ?

Comment: Not via API – in general apps can only delete stuff that was created through the same app before.

Comment: thanks for you reply. will try to delete with app.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to delete photo from facebook fan page cover album

Just like you make `\GET` and `\POST` request; do: `\DELETE` `/post_id`/ `photo_id`

But only if the photo is posted through your app!